# Roasting beef and lamb roasts together

Tags: meat, roasting

Can I roast @ 200 degress both a rib roast and a leg of lamb in same oven together without flavors transfering

Comment: Flavors will not transfer. (there was a similar question a while back, cannot find it)

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 200 C?

Comment: @Catija probably, but it *could* be "a bit too hot low-temperature cooking".

Comment: Are they in the same pan? Or just same oven, but different pans?

Answer (score 1):

I used to cook lamb (when I had to). I never cooked it with anything because the "lamby" flavor tended to transfer. Mutton, on the other hand, tastes a lot like mild beef, so I did cook those together. All I can suggest is that if you want to cook both in the same roaster, put one of the roasts into an oven bag to keep it separate from the other. There will be a modest transfer of aroma, but not of taste.

Comment: That's interesting...mutton is usually the stronger flavor which is why lamb is more often prefered. I happen to love lamb, mutton and goat.